# taglib.xml registered in web.xml not recognized by tomcat version 9

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf, primefaces

We created a facelets.taglib.xml file with some tags created for use in some JSF components.

For each tag created we create a class responsible for the event of each tag

**facelets.taglib.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <namespace>http://www.sgr.com.br/jsf</namespace>

    <tag>
        <tag-name>upperCase</tag-name>
        <handler-class>com.sistema.util.tag.UpperCaseTag</handler-class>
    </tag>

    <!-- more tag -->

</facelet-taglib>
```

**Classe upperCase**

```
package com.sistema.util.tag;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.FacesException;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletContext;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.TagConfig;
import javax.faces.view.facelets.TagHandler;

public class UpperCaseTag extends TagHandler {

    public UpperCaseTag() {
        this(null);
    }

    public UpperCaseTag(TagConfig config) {
        super(config);
    }

    public void apply(FaceletContext context, UIComponent componente) throws IOException, FacesException, FaceletException {
        this.configureKey(componente);
    }

    private void configureKey(UIComponent componente) {
        componente.getAttributes().put("onkeyup", "toUpperCase(this)");
        componente.getAttributes().put("onkeypress", "return noAccent(event);");
    }
}
```

**O modelo de páginas jsf contém a importação do arquivo javascript utils.js que contém o método toUpperCase e noAccent usado na classe UpperCase Tag**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        </f:facet>


        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/sentinel-layout.css" library="sentinel-layout" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/core-layout.css" library="sentinel-layout" />

        <ui:insert name="css" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>        

        <ui:include src="topbar.xhtml" />

        <ui:include src="/page/principal/menu.xhtml" />

        <div id="layout-portlets-cover" class="fontRegular">

            <p:messages id="messages" closable="true"/>

            <ui:insert name="content">
               Template
            </ui:insert>

        </div>

        <h:outputScript name="js/utils.js"  library="custom"/>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

**page where we use the upperCase tag in the input.**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:sgr="http://www.sgr.com.br/jsf"
                template="/WEB-INF/facelets/templates/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">

        <div class="Container100 ui-fluid">

            <div class="ContainerIndent">

                <h:form id="formFunID" prependId="false">
                    <p:panel id="pnlCamposID">

                        <p:outputLabel value="Nome completo:"/>
                        <p:inputText id="inptNome" value="#{funcionarioBean.funcionario.nome}">
                            <sgr:upperCase/>
                        </p:inputText>

                    </p:panel>
                </h:form>

            </div>

        </div>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

As image, the namespace is imported normally **xmlns: sgr = "http://www.sgr.com.br/jsf"** but typing the characters does not get upperCase

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>display-app</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>site.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener> 
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class> 
    </listener>

    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>sentinel</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.TRANSFORM_METADATA</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/facelets.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/primefaces-sentinel.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>timezone</param-name>
        <param-value>GMT-3</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
        <param-value>commons</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

[image]

We migrated the application to tomcat version 9 before we used wildfly, with this migration this tag stopped working.

The javascript file is loading normally in the browser.
If anyone knows if there is any configuration to be made by tomcat and can help.

Comment: The 'recognition' of taglibs is not something that tomcat does, nor PrimeFaces, nor plain java. It is done by the jsf implementation you use. So please add that AND the version of it to this post and remove all other tags (as they are not relevant to the problem). But if the problem is **autocompletion in your IDE** it is a plain IDE problem and not even a jsf one...

Comment: Two questions: why did you move from Wildfly to Tomcat? How is the server configured and what modules have been installed?

Comment: Thanks for the KG6ZVP response, the change was customer choice for the amount charged by an instance of wildfly by their hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kukeltje, the version of jsf I am using is the 2.2.13 made available by dependency <dependency>
<groupId> org.glassfish </ groupId>
<artifactId> javax.faces </ artifactId>
<version> $ {jsf.version} </ version>
</ dependency>